# Why am I getting an NSInternalInconsistencyException when setting up my Auto-Layout in Swift Storyboard?

Tags: swift, autolayout, storyboard, constraints, internals

this is my first Stack Overflow question so I apologize if it is worded incorrectly.
I am creating a simple scheduler app for a local barbershop. When trying to set up the constraints on my view controllers, I tried switching to iPad Pro (12.9 Inch), and my storyboard gave me an internal error. After trying to go back to iPhone 11, some views stayed the size of an iPad Pro and others returned. After relaunching xCode, I get this view.[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7VTb.jpg)

After reporting the bug, I check the log and this is what I see Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Exception reason: Failed to create work interval [log.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUMHI.png)

The only way I've been able to fix this is to clear all my constraints and my derived data, but when I start to constrain my views again, it reoccurs. Clearing derived data has not worked, restarting has not worked, so I need some help if any of you have been through this error. Thank you! I apologize for my beginner question as I am not used to writing on Stack Overflow.